# What is this やれ form?

Tags: grammar, meaning, parsing

> 予め名前を記入して**やれ**もしたが

What form is this やれ and what does it mean? It doesn't seem to be the imperative form of やる.

Comment: It's not や**り**もした?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It’s the ます-stem of やれる, which is the potential form of やる. The particle も (or は) may be inserted between a ます-stem and the auxiliary verb する like that.

やれ**も**した means the same as やること**も**できた. The latter expresses the potentiality by できた.